# What is the origin of the supplication: "O Allah, light my heart with knowledge"?

Tags: source-identification, dua, islamic-basis

There is a *du'a'* (supplication) that says:

> اللهم نور بالعلم قلبي، وافتح بطاعتك بدني، وخلص من الفتن سري، وقني شر
>   وساوس الشيطان، واجرني منه يا رحمن، حتى لا يكون له علي سلطان وقل ربي
>   زدنى علما
>
> O Allah, light my heart with knowledge, and open my body your
>   obedience, and save my inner secret from sedition, and protect me from
>   the evil whisperers of *Al-Shaytan*, and make me avoid him O' Rahman,
>   so he has no authority over me,  and say, "My Lord, increase me in
>   knowledge."
>
> Transliteration: *Allahummah nawwir bil-'ilmi qalbi, waftah bita'atika
>   badani, wakhalis minal fitani sirri, wa qini sharra waswaasi shaitan,
>   wa ajirni minhu yaa Rahmaan, hattaa laa yakuuna 'alayya sultaan, wa
>   qul rabbi zdni 'ilman.*

**Question:** What is the origin of this *du'a'*?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).